# Regex not working correctly on iOS

Tags: ios, regex

Can someone please explain the meaning of following regex :

> ^[+]?[0-9]{0,4}[ ]?(\([0-9]{1,6}\))?[0-9 ()/-]{4,}$

This does not allow me to validate **(0049) (0)151-544/187 29 or (0049)(0)15154418729**

I tried to debug and my understanding says that there is an issue with the number which has 2 open and closed brackets ().

If I make **(0049) (0)151-544/187 29 as (0049) 151-544/187 29** , this works.

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex `^[+]?[0-9]{0,4}[ ]?(\([0-9]{1,6}\))?[0-9 ()/-]{4,}$` expressed as

[image]

If You need group1 multiple times add `*` to that group

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: @RakeshKR Thanks for tool information :) it helps me to validate my custom regex.

Answer (score 1):

The above regex acceps only numbers within a single pair braces ie,() if you need multiple () to accpet add the asterisk(*)symbol before after the closing bracket

use the below regular expression instead.

```
^[+]?[0-9]{0,4}[ ]?(\([0-9]{1,6}\)*)?[0-9 ()/-]{4,}$
```

if its not worked replace the asterisk as your need

Answer (score 1):

**Can someone please explain the meaning of following regex**

See my decomposition of the string you submitted for review. BTW - This is a case in point that reference docs work because before this question I had not tried to use the NSRegularExpression. Thanks for the opportunity to learn something new.

```
^[+]?[0-9]{0,4}[ ]?(\([0-9]{1,6}\))?[0-9 ()/-]{4,}$
```

**Note** - My explanations are pulled directly from Table 1 and 2 of the reference link below.

`^` - Match at the beginning of a line

`[+]` - [pattern] Match any one character from the pattern.

`?` - Match zero or one times. Prefer one.

`[0-9]` - [pattern] Match any one character from the pattern.

`{0,4}` - Match between 0 and 4 times. Match as many times as possible, but not more than 4.

`[ ]` -  Match any one character from the pattern (in this case its a single whitespace)

`?` - Match zero or one times. Prefer one.

`(\([0-9]{1,6}\))` - (...) Capturing parentheses. Range of input that matched the parenthesized subexpression is available after the match

Within that subexpression we see:

`\` - Treat the following character as a literal, suppressing any special meaning. Backslash escaping in substitution text is only required for '$' and '\', but may be used on any other character without bad effects.

followed by `(` which means to treat the opening parenthesis as a literal

`[0-9]` - [pattern] Match any one character from the pattern.

`{1,6}` - Match between 1 and 6 times. Match as many times as possible, but not more than 6.

still within the subexpression we see:

`\` - Treat the following character as a literal, suppressing any special meaning. Backslash escaping in substitution text is only required for '$' and '\', but may be used on any other character without bad effects.

followed by `)` which means to treat the closing parenthesis as a literal

`?` - Match zero or one times. Prefer one. (**This seems to be the problem, you are only matching zero or once here**)

`[0-9 ()/-]` - [pattern] Match any one character from the pattern.

`{4,}` - Match at least 4 times. Possessive Match.

`$` - Match at the end of a line. See NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines and the m character expression in Table 4.

See the [apple documentation on NSRegularExpression Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for further explanations of the metacharacters and operators.

**Other note on \:**

`\` - Quotes the following character. Characters that must be quoted to be treated as literals are * ? + [ ( ) { } ^ $ | \ . /

**Interesting Note:**

I found that the escapedPatternForString method can produce a pattern sample allowing one to reverse engineer an escaped pattern string from one's desired output. It doesn't perfectly output the pattern but does help with the metacharacters..

```
NSString *sample = @"(0049) (0)151-544/187 29";
NSString *pattern = [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:sample];

//Pattern sample: \(0049\) \(0\)151-544\/187 29
NSLog(@"Pattern sample: %@", pattern);
```